# How to count number of values of a variable in swift?

Tags: swift, api

I am working on this screen:

[image]

This screen has questions and I am getting these questions from the API. Now, above the question I have a collection view which has buttons[1,2,...] and these buttons count must be equals to the  numbers of questions I have from the API.

Now, this is the struct I made to get the values from the API.

```
struct Questions {
    var id:String = ""
    var user_id:String = ""
    var questionset_id:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var type:String = ""
    var timetosolve:String = ""
    var longtypeanswer:String = ""
    .......
}
```

These variables in this struct holds the questions, options for the questions and everything.

This is how I am appending this data:

```
ServerClass.sharedInstance.sendMultipartRequestToServerWithHeader_POST(urlString: "url", sendJson: [:], successBlock: { (json) in
            if json["status"] == "ok" {
                for i in 0..<json["data"].count {
                    self.list_Questions.append(Questions.init(id:  json["data"][i]["id"].stringValue, user_id:  json["data"][i]["user_id"].stringValue
                                                              questionset_id:  json["data"][i]["questionset_id"].stringValue,
                                                              name:  json["data"][i]["name"].stringValue, type:  json["data"][i]["type"].stringValue, timetosolve:  json["data"][i]["timetosolve"].stringValue, longtypeanswer:  json["data"][i]["longtypeanswer"].stringValue))
```

And this is the collection view code:

```
ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return list_Question.count // this is where I have to return the count. Also this doesn't work.
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell
        }
        
        
    }
```

How can I make the count of the collection view buttons equals to the questions I have in the API?

Comment: I see you're stuck in this quiz app since a long time, I came across a lot of questions regarding this app lately, and the only reason you're stuck  is because your questions are very unclear with a limited code. Please add some code. Show how and where you're appending the fetched API data for further help.

Comment: Your API code has no relevance to the question. How does your collection view delegate looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it but,

I assume you have an Int Array list_Question to hold questionNumbers right? and you want this array to have equal count as your other Array list_Questions right?

```
var list_Question = [Int]()

ServerClass.sharedInstance.sendMultipartRequestToServerWithHeader_POST(urlString: "url", sendJson: [:], successBlock: { (json) in
            if json["status"] == "ok" {
                for i in 0..<json["data"].count {
                    list_Question.append(i+1)
                    // and the rest of your code.. Now your both arrays will have the same count.
                }
             //reload data..
            }
}
```

Comment: See, I have a struct where I have many variables right ? and every variable holds many values. For instance, the "name" variable in struct has questions for the app. When I am appending the struct data, I am making use of the iteration so that I get a new question every time. Now, what I want is that the collection view buttons to be equal to the number of questions that "name" variable has.

Comment: you mean to say if for example you have 8 questions, then you want the collectionView buttons counter  to be from 1 to 8? If i am right then that's what the code does. If you have for example 8 questions, you will have 8 iterations and in every iteration i am appending the iterationNumber+1. so you will have equal number for both of your arrays MaM.